# OpenFeint Notifications from the bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, game-center, openfeint

I have both game center and open feint integrated into my app. When the notification comes up to tell you that you successfully logged in, the open feint overlaps the game center notification. How do you move the notification to the bottom instead. I saw the documentation but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work. I see the `enum ENotificationPosition` and it includes `ENotificationPosition_BOTTOM` but where am I supposed to put that code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is specify this in the settings dictionary that you use to initialize OpenFeint. For example,

```
NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait], OpenFeintSettingDashboardOrientation,
                          kShortAppName, OpenFeintSettingShortDisplayName,
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingAlwaysAskForApprovalInDebug,
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], OpenFeintSettingGameCenterEnabled,
                          window, OpenFeintSettingPresentationWindow,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:ENotificationPosition.ENotificationPosition_BOTTOM_LEFT], OpenFeintSettingNotificationPosition,
                          nil];

[OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:kOFProductKey 
                          andSecret:kOFProductSecret
                     andDisplayName:kLongAppName
                        andSettings:settings
                       andDelegates:delegates];
```